# IsNetworkavailable property always returning true

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to find weather my windows phone internet or network connection is on in c# code? For me, `isnetworkavailable` returns true always.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `GetIsNetworkAvailable` which returns a result based on the network interfaces available. Like this:

```
bool isNetworkAvailable=NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
if(!isNetworkAvailable)
{
   //your code

}
```

Comment: its return true always. if network/dataconnection off but wifi on its returning true..

Comment: @SambhavPani: you should say in your question that you're talking about the case where the machine has a working network connection but no internet connectivity.  Keep in mind that it isn't always sensible to even try to detect this; what if the user has connectivity to the particular site they need but not to the sites Windows uses to test internet access?  It is usually better to just try to connect and see whether it works or not.

Comment: By a lucky coincidence, an example of this problem showed up shortly after your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25817223/886887

Answer (score 0):

The only way to find is to subscribe to the event `DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged`.

Once you have received that event (which is guaranteed on happen on **changes** of the network), then you will know whether you are connected or not by querying the [various apis here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation).

There is [a sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.networkavailabilitychanged) that will exactly tell you how to do so.

You can also check what kind of network you are on with [NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype), however be careful as calling this API might freeze the calling thread (or the UI if you're running off the main thread) under certain circumstances (connecting to a wifi for instance is one of them).
You should be fine however if you follow the examples, once again !